Does anyone know the name of this mental institution movie?
The movie is about a man who kills his sister's rapist. He ends up in a mental hospital. While there, he finds a girl with whom he will escape with later on. He also becomes friends with a large chubby man with schizophrenia. Later on he meets the father of the man he killed and finds out he killed the wrong person.
There's one crazy man in the asylum who bites a live rabbit in the neck out in the yard.
Sorry for remembering so little about the movie. Would appreciate any help.

Country\language? Approximate year of release?

English, and i think its from 2004 and above, kinda new movie, the main character looked alot like the actor "Ryan Philippe"

@DanielElsby Could you explain why did you rollback the edits? They were only spelling and grammar improvements.

sorry im all new to this site, and english isnt my first language..

Sounds to me like it's the movie On The Inside.  I'm new here and don't know if there's a real standard to writing replies.  Sorry.

Welcome to the site and thanks for your contribution. You could flesh out the answer a little and explain why you think this is the searched movie. In which way does it match the question's descriptions? Also if you're new, you might also want to take a look at the [tour] and the [help].

that is the movie, thank you man ! :)
